# Hand shaking problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Mr. X throw a party and 99 people came to the party. Every person shook hands with every other person.
How many handshakes were there exactly?
and how to calculate this number conveniently? for example, if the number 99 is changed, how would one find the result again?

Comment: Do you know what binomial coefficient is? I think it is just ${100}\choose{2}$ if we include mr X. It seems that easy to me maybe i am missing something

Comment: The [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

We can reframe this as a graph problem. Let every person be a vertex, and if two people shook hands with each other, add an edge between them. Now, what we want to find is the number of edges in this graph.

Since everyone shook hands with every other person, the degree of each vertex is $99$. There are $100$ people, applying the handshaking lemma, we get $|E|= \frac{\sum_{v\in G} \deg{v}}{2}=\frac{100\cdot 99}{2}=50\cdot 99.$ We note that this is actually the complete graph, and hence the number of edges is also $\binom{100}{2}$.

If you are referring to the number of people coming to the party being changed to $k$ people and everyone still shook hands with everyone, the answer is then the number of edges in the complete graph on $k+1$ vertices, which is $\binom{k+1}{2}$.

However, if you are referring to the number of people each person shook hands with is changed from $99$ to some $k$, with the number of people in the party staying the same, the answer is then $|E|=\frac{\sum_{v\in G} \deg{v}}{2}=\frac{100\cdot k}{2}=50k$.